# Ассемблер из 32 bit в 64

Tags: ассемблер, freepascal

Есть код ассемблер, который я использую в 32 битном Делфи.

```
function RotateRightBits(const Value:LongWord; const Bits:Byte):LongWord;register;assembler;
asm
 MOV CL,DL
 ROR EAX,CL
end;
```

Я переписываю программу в 64 битном FreePascal и столкнулся со сложностью перевода этого кода. Так как он возвращает совсем не то число что в 32 битном.

Аналог кода на Делфи работает в 10 раз дольше, по этому меня он не устраивает.

```
function RotateRightBits(const Value:LongWord;const Bits:Byte):LongWord;
var I,B:integer;
begin
 Result := Value;
 if Bits >= 32 then B := Bits mod 32
 else B := Bits;
 for I := 1 to B do
  if Result and 1 = 0 then Result := Result shr 1
  else Result := (Result shr 1) or $80000000;
 end;
```

Сильно сложно переписать 32 битный код ассемблера под 64 битные регистры, чтоб он работал идентично?

Comment: Входные и выходные параметры также должны быть 32-х битные?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov нет, 64 битные

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В x32 параметры в функцию передаются через регистры eax, edx, ecx, а возвращаемый результат передается через регистр eax.

В x64 параметры в функцию передаются через регистры rcx, rdx, r8, r9, а возвращаемый результат передается через регистр rax.

Поэтому функцию нужно написать вот так

```pascal
function RotateRightBits(Value: LongWord; Bits: Byte): LongWord; register; assembler;
asm
  {$IFDEF CPUx64}
  mov rax, rcx
  {$ENDIF}
  mov cl, dl
  ror eax, cl
end;
```

Если же 64 битная функция должна работать с 64 битными значениями, то нужно написать так

```pascal
// Тип NativeUInt имеет различный размер в зависимости от платформы
function RotateRightBits(Value: NativeUInt; Bits: Byte): NativeUInt; register; assembler;
asm
  {$IFDEF CPUx32}
  mov cl, dl
  ror eax, cl
  {$ELSE}
  mov rax, rcx
  mov cl, dl
  ror rax, cl
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

Comment: выдает ошибку test.pas Error: Asm: signed dword value exceeds bounds 4294967295 на строке and rax, 0ffffffffh

Comment: эта инструкция и не нужна: на amd64 32-х битные инструкции обнуляют старшую часть регистра...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Да, без нее все заработало, Спасибо!

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @BadMan добавил вариант для 64-битных значений