# Сдвиг влево в цикле

Tags: pascal

Написал простую програмку для теста, когда увидел что у меня в другой программе идут неправильные данные.
В ней сначала действия идут без цикла, а потом повторяется то же самое, но в цикле. Второй результат совершенно разный. Не могу понять почему, помогите.

```
program Test;
var
 i:integer;
begin
 writeln(1 shl 5);
 writeln(1 shl 54);
 i:=5;
 while i<55 do begin
  writeln(1 shl i);
  inc(i,49);
 end;
end.
```

Результат работы программы

```
32
18014398509481984
32
4194304
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kомпилятор вычислил `1 shl 54` во время компиляции и увеличил размер результата до `BigInteger`(?).

---

Так. Увидел добавление в комментарии. Начнем ликбез. Когда выполняется

```
var c: QWord;
...
c := 1 shl i; // этa строчка
```

вычисление `1 shl i` не знает, что результат будет присвоен переменной типа `QWord`. Или по-другому: правая часть оператора присваивания ничего не знает про левую.

```
var c, d: QWord;
...
d := 1;
c := d shl i;
WriteLn(c);
```

Или без `c`:

```
var d: QWord;
...
d := 1;
WriteLn(d shl i);
```

Comment: Даже если я заранее обявлю тип QWord, который является самым большим типом integer в паскале, результат будет точно такой же. В цикле, после определенного значения, которое превышает обычный integer, результаты начинают выводить не правильно.

Comment: @BadMan Мне плохо видны мысли в Вашей голове. Где Вы заранее объявите `QWord`?

Comment: заранее объявлю переменную типа QWord, допустиv var c:QWord, и буду делать вывод этой переменной после расчета. c:=1 shl i; writeln(c);

Comment: @BadMan Вы придуриваетесь? "и буду делать вывод это" - что это значит?

Comment: @BadMan Я уже проверил. Так и есть - как я сказал. Убираю слово "подозреваю".

Comment: хорошо. Как сделать чтоб в цикле правильно считало?

Comment: @BadMan Пардон - перепутал право и лево.

Comment: Да, если 1 заменить на переменную типа QWord, тогда считает правильно. Странная логика у комплиятора, ограничивать результат типом int, когда в левой части явно затребован BigInt.

Comment: @BadMan Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Comment: @BadMan Старый ответ тоже можно принять. Спасибо. - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1345585/%d0%90%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-32-bit-%d0%b2-64